# How to save data before app enters multasking

Tags: objective-c, multitasking, saving-data

Im trying to find a way to save data before my app enters multitasking, i know how to save data, but i dont know what method to use to save it before the app enters multitasking.

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
```

this one? because i have everything set up to save, but it doesn't seem to be saving it, and im positive that its the multitasking part because it works on the ios 3 simulator. Do i have to save it in the delegate?

Thanks,
Jacob

EDIT: On the IOS 3 one i have it saving data in the

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Jacob, You have to save it in the application delegate of your app.

The method `-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` gets called when the device enters standby mode or when the app is switched to background.
So the saving part you can add to this method .

Also to make the app save data for iOS versions < 4.0 , add the saving code to `applicationWillTerminate`: also.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method what is the method Apple recommends

`-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

but you can also use

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`

which is the method that is called instead of

`- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Delegate method:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

This allows you to react when the application becomes inactive. See the Docs for more information.

Happy coding :)